# .Net Core: Where to store configuration data which should be available to various applications

Tags: .net-core, configuration

In the olde' days we used to use the windows registry to store configuration settings which then would be available to multiple applications running on the same machine. A root key would be known to all participating applications and they could find what they need underneath that root key. This approach was required because App-A might know nothing about App-B's installation location.

Since we're slowly moving everything into .Net Core, what is the recommended approach to solve an issue like this one? We are after a solution where the configuration data is stored in one and only one place: A single file to rule them all. ;) And in a perfect world the "storage" would not require any elevated privileges.

Comment: We use environment variables.  Makes working with containers easy too.